# Referencing a figure throwing up '??', not '1'

Tags: cross-referencing

I've only very recently started with LaTeX and can't seem to get this to work!

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure} [h!]
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=40mm]{UNSWlogo.jpg}
\caption{UNSW Emblem}\label{fig:logo}
\end{figure}
Please see Figure \ref{fig:logo} blah blah blah
\end{document}
```

Its giving me

> Figure ??

instead of

> Figure 1

as expected or an actual number.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Duplicate, but closed without an answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102771/21591

Answer (score 5):

You need to compile your main file twice to get the references right.

The first time, the references get written to the `.aux` file, which is then read on the second compilation to replace the `??` with the right references.

Comment: I'm using latexian, and i've pressed 'preview' twice? That compiles it doesn't it? So it should work... but it doesn't. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @yorkie1990: Is there an option with the LaTeXian preferences that clears all the auxiliary files (like a clean-up) created from a compile?

Comment: I don't know latexian, but I guess it should. I've turned your question code into a [`MWE`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) (which you should always provide on this site, it will help you to isolate the bug and others to reproduce it); check it that works on latexian.

Comment: @werner I can't seem to find anything in the preferences that does that.

Comment: @yorkie1990: I don't have a Mac to test this. My guess was that there is some preference set to erase auxiliary files after a compilation - something that might cause this problem. However, other Mac users around here would be able to help out, I'm sure...

Comment: @Werner Hmm, yeah you guys are most definitely right. I just ran it twice in TeXworks and it worked! However i would prefer to use LaTeXian if possible. Would it be best to write another question about how/where to unselect the option that may erase aux. files after it compiles? Or hope that someone else sees this post that can help?

Comment: @yorkie1990: While things are quiet across the globe at this moment, consider visiting [the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) and ask around there. I already posted a request there, so maybe something will come from it. I'm sure things will be resolved.

Comment: @yorkie1990 I never rely on pre-configured compilation work-flows of text editors but always use the command line or scripts/makefiles written by me. This helps to understand what is going on and to stay the master of everything.

Comment: @yorkie1990 -- please add the information that you're using latexian to the original question.  as it stands, the generality of the question is such that the simple answer "compile the file twice" would answer it.  it's easier for someone else looking for this information to find it when it's all in one place (question).